# How to add a custom controller to view

Tags: iphone, c#-4.0, xamarin.ios, uitableview, monodevelop

I am new to monotouch as well as iphone development.
I have a controller say firstcontroller with a UITableView.
I have another custom controller say customcontroller.

so how do i add my custom controller to firstcontroller. such that both(Uitableview and firstcontroller) are visible.

thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Something like firstcontroller.View.AddSubview(customcontroller.View); should do the trick. Or to have a third controller containing both controller's views.
Be aware that by adding the second view to the first view all its controls are placed relatively to the first controllers view.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Apple documentation:

"Each custom view controller object you create is responsible for managing all of the views in a single view hierarchy. In iPhone applications, the views in a view hierarchy traditionally cover the entire screen, but in iPad applications they may cover only a portion of the screen. The one-to-one correspondence between a view controller and the views in its view hierarchy is the key design consideration. YOU SHOULD NOT USE MULTIPLE CUSTOM VIEW CONTROLLERS TO MANAGE DIFFERENT PORTIONS OF THE SAME VIEW HIERARCHY. Similarly, you should not use a single custom view controller object to manage multiple screens worth of content."

You're going to get into trouble when it comes to autorotation if you have firstcontroller and customcontroller each controlling a separate view in the same view hierarchy. Would it be possible to make the table view and customcontroller's View both UIView fields inside the firstcontroller class? Then you could size and position the two UIView objects as subviews within firstcontroller's View property during firstcontroller's ViewDidLoad() method.